# O Div Load está obsoleto?

Tags: ajax

Estou usando `$("#minhadiv").load("url.php");` mas o Chrome está dizendo que é obsoleto, é isso mesmo? Então como utilizar?

Comment: loda? não sei se isso funciona não, drmcarvalho editou e ainda por cima mal editado

Comment: Referência direta [Discussao acima da sua dúvida](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733)

Comment: O `.load` não está deprecado/obsoleto: http://api.jquery.com/load/ podes mostrar um exemplo do código que gera isso?

Comment: Ola Sergio, muito estranho, ignorei o aviso e continuei meu trabalho, do nada parou a mensagem do Chrome, acho que alguma linha estava atrapalhando a identificação correta da rotina. A rotina é grande mas o trecho que estava na dúvida é este:


 `BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Localizar Pastor',
                message: $('<div>Carregando...</div>').load('/solicitacao/solicitacao.localizar'),
                draggable: true,
                buttons: [{`